# tar command on AIX is not working unzip

Tags: tar, aix

tar -zxvf unzip and untar command work on RHEL and Solaris however the not working on AIX 5/6/7 what is the equivalent command?

Comment: Try this `gzip -d -c <insertnamehere.tgz> | tar -xvf -`

Comment: This work, thank you

Answer (score 1):

A good answer was provided in a comment. Adding an answer, though.

The portable version of tar -zxvf is that I reach for on old non-linux unix systems is:

```
gzip -dc foo.tgz | tar xvf -
```

Answer (score 1):

```
gunzip <filename>.tar.gz
tar xvf <filename>.tar
```

Note that `gunzip` command outputs a .tar file. Then `tar xvf` untars this .tar file.